# Pivoting and getting #1111 - Invalid use of group function for this query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm try to Pivoting and getting #1111 - Invalid use of group function for this query. I really need help here.

```
SELECT pack.ActionName, up.Name
SUM(IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SchoolYear, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) = 'X', COUNT(tph.UniqueActionPackageId)*pack.TotalPrice, 0)) AS Total_Revenue_X,
AVERAGE(IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SchoolYear, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) = 'X', Total_Revenue_X/COUNT(tph.UniqueActionPackageId),0)) AS Rataan_Kelas_X,
SUM(IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SchoolYear, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) = 'XI', COUNT(tph.UniqueActionPackageId)*pack.TotalPrice, 0)) AS Total_Revenue_XI,
AVERAGE(IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SchoolYear, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) = 'XI', Total_Revenue_XI/COUNT(tph.UniqueActionPackageId),0)) AS Rataan_Kelas_XI,
SUM(IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SchoolYear, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) = 'XII', COUNT(tph.UniqueActionPackageId)*pack.TotalPrice, 0)) AS Total_Revenue_XII,
AVERAGE(IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SchoolYear, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) = 'XII', Total_Revenue_XII/COUNT(tph.UniqueActionPackageId),0)) AS Rataan_Kelas_XII
FROM packages AS pack
JOIN transaction_package_history AS tph ON pack.ActionPackagesId = tph.UniqueActionPackageId
JOIN user_profile AS up ON up.UniqueId = tph.UserId 
GROUP BY pack.ActionName;
```

Can you guys help me

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.  A non-working query generally does not provide much information.

Comment: You are currently trying to mix functions which aggregate across multiple rows (SUM, COUNT, AVG) with individual columns from a single row; that's not going to work. Try to write out in plain English the calculation you're trying to make, and some sample data that could be pasted into a tool like https://dbfiddle.uk/ to test solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are trying to write something like this:

```
SELECT p.ActionName, up.Name
       SUM(CASE WHEN SchoolYear LIKE '%X %' THEN p.TotalPrice END) as Total_Revenue_X,
       AVG(CASE WHEN SchoolYear LIKE '%X %' THEN p.TotalPrice END) as Rataan_Kelas_X,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SchoolYear LIKE '%XI %' THEN p.TotalPrice END) as Total_Revenue_XI,
       AVG(CASE WHEN SchoolYear LIKE '%XI %' THEN p.TotalPrice END) as Rataan_Kelas_XI,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SchoolYear LIKE '%XII %' THEN p.TotalPrice END) as Total_Revenue_XI,
       AVG(CASE WHEN SchoolYear LIKE '%XII %' THEN p.TotalPrice END) as Rataan_Kelas_XI,
FROM packages p JOIN
     transaction_package_history tph
     ON p.ActionPackagesId = tph.UniqueActionPackageId JOIN
     user_profile up
     ON up.UniqueId = tph.UserId 
GROUP BY p.ActionName;
```